# Quick and dirty way to make forms for editing fields in MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have a seriously ridiculous deadline to meet because I'm picking up from a disgruntled developer. I have a database with a few tables and some one-to-one mappings, nothing too complicated.

I need to create a backend for searching and editing these tables in some kind of HTML form style (not necessarily web-based if there is a better solution like MS Access or something).

I suspect I'm being vague, simple example:

Customer table:

```
CustomerID   Name    Email
```

Bookings table:

```
BookingID    CustomerID    Departure_Date    Return_Date
```

I need the easiest, quickest solution that will allow a non-programmer client to create, read, update and delete records from these tables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest http://www.ajaxcrud.com/ if you really want to have something inside your application.

Comment: That thing is really really awesome!

Answer (score 5):

If the deadline is *seriously ridiculous* then [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net) with a bit of explanation to the client.

Comment: It is a truly ridiculous deadline :) I'll keep that in mind as a last resort

Answer (score 2):

Web frameworks essentially specialize in creating very fast CRUD interfaces to databases.

What you're saying would be incredibly easy in Django, because all you need to do is define the models to match your existing database, and then turn on the Admin interface. That would be just what you asked for with zero programming, only configuration.  Django is Python, however.

I suggest configuring a PHP web framework like Symfony, CodeIgniter (or it's decendants, Yii and Kohana) or CakePHP.

Comment: Good idea. The site I'm working on runs a pretty dreadful custom CMS. Is it possibly to generate the code with CakePHP and extract it somehow or does it have to be integrated with CakePHP?

Comment: I'd say anything you write with a framework will require the framework libraries to run... they're not meant to generate stand alone code.  It might be possible, I guess... you could extract all the SQL and rewrite or something after you had it set up, but that sounds like more work. I'm not that familiar with Cake specifically. I'd imagine it wouldn't be too hard to integrate the Cake system with your current CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [DBKiss](http://www.gosu.pl/dbkiss/) it's one PHP file you can just upload.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [TOAD](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) for MySQL, or a similar IDE.  That would be about the quickest, simplest way.  You would just need to show the user a few simple steps.